# Python: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(54, 'ECONNRESET')",))

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I don't understand why the connection aborted, I have included headers and cookies in my request. Any input would be highly appreciated.

```py
import requests


url = 'https://fp.trafikverket.se/boka/#/search/SPHhISIPAfhPP/5/0/0/0'
s = requests.session()
res = s.get(url)
cookies = dict(res.cookies)
headers = dict(res.headers)
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'
r = s.post(url, 
    cookies=cookies, headers=headers).text

>>> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(54, 'ECONNRESET')",))
```

Comment: what data you're trying to `post` to the URL, indeed?

Comment: I’m not posting anything at the moment since I can’t establish  a connection, but I will post a payload to fill the form that is on the site

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code, it works.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://fp.trafikverket.se/boka/#/search/SPHhISIPAfhPP/5/0/0/0'
s = requests.session()
res = s.get(url)
cookies = dict(res.cookies)
headers = dict(res.headers)
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'
data = {}
r = s.post(url, data = json.dumps(data), cookies = cookies, headers = headers).text
```

Comment: Thank you for the input but it does not work, it says (is swedish) multiple error messeges in the html. As: `Your browser is not supported`, `Cookies in your browser has to be activated`, `Third party cookies has to be activated`, `Your browser can not be set to private mode`. It does not return the same html as when visiting the site in the browser directly.

Comment: Maybe you're looking at the bottom of the page, please scroll up and it's exactly similar to the page. I just inspect (`ctrl+u`) and compare them, responses are equal. Can you try `print(r)`

Comment: I believe it's the information from `https://fp.trafikverket.se/boka/occasion-bundles` that I'm after.

Comment: I have inspected, and the form that is supposed to be filled is not present in the response, for example the div class `form-group` is not present.